# Tenses query Past Tense

Tags: tenses

In the sentence "I was awake", why is it 'awake' and not 'awoke' since it is a simple past tense sentence?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here stems from the fact that "awake" can function as both a verb and an adjective. The verb "to awake":

> awake (verb) - stop sleeping; wake from sleep.

The adjective "awake":

> awake (adjective) - not asleep (a state of being).

In the sentence "I was awake," the verb is "was", the simple past form of "to be" and the word "awake" is functioning as an adjective.

If you want to use "awake" as a verb, you could simply say:

> I awoke.

Comment: Thanks much! Your explanation is lucid and just want is needed!